# C# + SharpDevelop: screwed up resourcemanager after changing root namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces, root, sharpdevelop, resourcemanager

After recognizing that my project already exists under the used *solutionname* i decided to rename the whole solution. I need to do that because I want to share the source code on my homepage as well as the application itself and don't want it to look to users like a copy of some other project that already exist.

I changed all namespaces in every file as well as the assemblyname, the root namespace and the resourcemanager instance call from "OldName" to "NewName" like so:

```
resManager = new ResourceManager("NewName.Resources.Manifest", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

After doing that, I recompiled which worked without any errors. Unfortunately I get a runtime error with a `System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException` when calling the first `resManager.GetString();` method. So the application is not able to see the resources anymore. But why?

Folder structure and all the other source files did not changed. I restored my backup and figured out, that it is not possible to simply change the root namespace as well as the `resourcemanager`. There must be something I just do not know.

Any help would be great :-)

Here is what I'm doing:

```
namespace NewName
{

//...

ResourceManager resManager;
CultureInfo cultureInfo;

Settings settingsFromFile = new Settings();

settingsFromFile.readSettings();

if (settingsFromFile.Language == "german")
   cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("de");
else
   cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en");

resManager = new ResourceManager("NewName.Resources.Manifest", System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

//...

contextMenuStripDoFencyStuff.MenuItems.Add(resManager.GetString("contextMenuStripDoFencyStuffText",cultureInfo)); <-- this is where the exception occurs

}
```

The name of the resx file is *"Manifest.de.resx"* and *"Manifest.en.resx"*. These files are in *"ProjectFolder/Resources/"*.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i got it back to work. For everyone who will experience the same, here is the solution:

I started a new solution with the solution wizard. Added all Projects back to it including the Source files and compiled it.

Thats all. Seems to be a specific problem with SharpDevelop?!

Regards, Steven.